# ListView element does not get selected

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListViewFragment class which is configured to choice_mode_single. I am using a custom CursorAdapter to populate the listView. Problem is when I select something from the LV it does not get highlighted by a blue background. but, only the text gets bold. Code:

```
public class CategoryFragment extends ListFragment{

int lastPosition;
DatabaseControl db;
OnCategorySelectedListener callBack;
CategoryCursorAdapter cursorInstance;
public interface OnCategorySelectedListener{

    public void onCategorySelected(int categoryName);   
}
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    db=new DatabaseControl(this.getActivity());
    db.open();
    getListView().setFastScrollEnabled(true);
    cursorInstance=new CategoryCursorAdapter(getActivity(), db.getCategoryCursor(""), CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER, "category_name",0, db);
    getListView().setAdapter(cursorInstance);

    getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    this.setListShown(true);

    this.getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(listViewLongClick);
    if(savedInstanceState!=null)
        getListView().setItemChecked(savedInstanceState.getInt("position"), true);

}




@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try{
        callBack=(OnCategorySelectedListener) activity;
    }

    catch(ClassCastException e){

        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()+" must implement OnCategorySelectedListener");
    }
}


@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("position", lastPosition);

}
```

Comment: have you created a list selector?

Comment: No. How is that craeted? please give me an example

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps to create a ListView selector,

- First of all you have to create a selector in drawable folder for your ListView row like,

> `list_selector.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" android:state_activated="true"/>
   <item android:drawable="@android:color/black"/>
</selector>
```

- Then apply the list_selector.xml to parent view of your ListView row as a background.
- Then set your ListView as ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE using `mListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE)`

So, your final code stuff would be something like,

```
  mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
  mListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
  MyAdapter mAdapter = new MyAdapter();
  mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
  mListView.setSelection(0);         // setting 0th position selected by default
  mListView.setItemChecked(0, true);
```

You can also check my [demo example from github](https://github.com/lalit3686/ListSelectorActivity)